# How do i create a loop to iterate between 2 numbers(years)?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem where i need to iterate been two different numbers or years. So for example. My start year is 1993 and my end year is 2014. How do i print out the year for year in between starting at 1993 and ending at 2014? Also for each year printed i need to add it to an array.

My assumption was to use a While loop like

```
var myYear = [];
var theYear;

while(startyear <= endYear){

myYear.push(startyear)
startyear++
}
```

Comment: It's ok , only what you need is to initialize the : startyear and endyear  before while loop

Comment: What does not work with your code?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I did forget to initialize. And I was wondering if this was the best way to do this.

Comment: Yes that is the best way.  Do you have a real question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare and initialize your variables.

Like this:

```
var startYear = 1993;
var endYear = 2014;
var yearArray = [];

while (startYear <= endYear) {
    yearArray.push(startYear);
    startYear++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `for` loop?

```
var year, 
    myYear = [];

for (year = startyear; year <= endYear; year ++){
   myYear.push(year)
}
```